# Why can't I assign element.innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

Why can't I store the reference to `some_var.innerHTML` to a variable and then modify it?

What rule is governing this?

HTML

```
<div id = "out">
test
</div>
```

It works if I do it directly.

```
var out = document.getElementById("out");
var res = out.innerHTML;
res = "foo";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yo1oajmf/

Answer (score 1):

You;re assigning it to `res` and then re-assigning res. This code does not assign anything to `innerHTML`.

```
out.innerHTML = "foo";
```

This is how you change the innerHTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working. It's just that you are storing the `innerHTML` in `res` and then overwriting that on the very next line. Also,you aren't doing anything with `res` after assigning it the value of `"foo"`.

> **You must also understand that when you store the `innerHTML`, you are stoing a COPY of the data. If you want to modify the `innerHTML`,
>   you must write back to it.**

This example reads the first `div`s value and then writes that plus `foo` to the second div.

```js
var out = document.getElementById("out");
var res = out.innerHTML     // Store the HTML 
res = res + " foo";         // Adjust the data
out.innerHTML = res;        // Write the new data back to the HTML element
```

```html
<div id = "out">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because assigning to `res` isn't the same as assigning to `innerHTML`; even if you previously assigned `innerHTML` to `res`.

When you say `res = element.innerHTML`, you're assigning the contents of `innerHTML` to `res`. When you then say `res = "something else"`, you're changing what `res` is assigned to.

Saying `res = element.innerHTML` does *not* mean that any changes made to `res` are reflected in `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the following code the innerHTML vaue i.e test will be assigned to the variable `res`.

```
    var out = document.getElementById("out").;
    var res = out.innerHTML;
```

This code is nothing but,

```
    var res = document.getElementById("out").innerHTML; // res = "test"
```

After that you are overwriting the value of res (i.e test) by "foo".

Answer (score 0):

If you used jQuery you can simply do the following:

```
$("#out").html("foo");
```

Comment: But the OP isn't using JQuery and you didn't answer the question.